# Maintain a subset of Django app along with full app

Tags: django, git, version-control

I'm working on a Django project for a large organization, and the full app will be for internal, private use, while a subset of the view functions and templates will also need to be available publicly. Due to IT constraints, the public portion will be on a different server, and won't be able to use the same files (but it will be able to query the database on the private server).

Is there a way to maintain a subset of the app's files on a separate server?

For example, if the private version has view functions a, b, and c, the public version will only use c. And the public version will only need the relevant template files, etc.

Does Django have some way of accomplishing this? Or Git, somehow (maybe gitignore)? I'm just trying to save myself from having to manually copy all updates from the full version to the partial version.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of thing that Django's app structure is for.  You could make the shared functionality a standalone pluggable app, managed as its own git repository.  The projects that depend on it can include it in their requirements.txt and settings files.  When you update the shared functionality, you increment the project version, and then update the requirements files.

Comment: That sounds clever - thanks! So there'd be a parent app that'd be the internal stuff, and then the child app would be the shared functionality for the internal and public stuff? Is project version in settings.py? I've never used project version before.

Comment: Depends how your projects are structured.  The setup I've used is an app with common business logic, which is used in both a public-facing project and a private-facing project.  Your child & parent may be a better fit for your projects.  App version is a git release tag on the repository, so your projects can be clear about which version of the shared application they're currently using.